# Como puedo conectar my archivo HTML a el localhost

Tags: php, javascript, html, mercadopago

estoy probando integrar Mercado Pago a mi sitio Web y  por ahora voy bien solo que tengo un inconveniente y es que al darle a pagar me dice que algo anduvo mal. Teniendo esto en cuenta quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que cuando corra mi pagina en el localhost:3000 me vaya al archivo index.html de mi pagina. Hasta ahora tengo varios archivos, y quiero que el localhost:3000/productos me lleve a la seccion productos. Aqui mi index.js

```
const app = express();

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Conectado");
});
```

Se que tengo que enlazarlo con el app.post pero no se como hacer que me dirija a mi archivo html. He hecho unas pruebas en otras carpetas con codigos de este estilo:

```
app.post("/villanos", function(req, res){
    const nuevoVillano = req.body;
    villanos.push(nuevoVillano);
    res.json(nuevoVillano);
});
```

Y otra duda, tengo que poner en cada uno de mis archivos html un script src que me lleve al index.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eso (si es que he entendido bien), no hace falta nada de código. Solamente tienes que poner el archivo en la carpeta htdocs de xampp. Para /productos, solamente tendrás que crear una carpeta dentro de htdocs llamada productos, y dentro crear otro index.html.

Comment: Muchas gracias!